# What is the most efficient and readable way to create a list of lists of integer ranges in Python?

Tags: python, list, math, integer

I like to learn efficient ways of creating lists in Python. I found myself in need of a list of lists of integers that looks like this:

```
[[5904],
 [5904, 5905],
 [5904, 5905, 5906],
 [5904, 5905, 5906, 5907],
 [5904, 5905, 5906, 5907, 5908],
 [5904, 5905, 5906, 5907, 5908, 5909]]
```

I am neither an expert programmer or theoretical mathematician so I mashed together the following function in Python to produce that list of lists:

```
def running_list_of_incremented_integer_lists(start, end):
    single_integer_list = new_list = [start]
    integer_lists = [single_integer_list]
    for integer in range(start, end + 1):
        new_list = copy(new_list)
        for _integer in range(integer, integer + 1):
            new_list.append(_integer + 1)
        integer_lists.append(new_list)

    return integer_lists
```

So my questions are these:

- Is there a more efficient and/or Pythonic way to write this bit of code?
- Are there any modules in Python that would help in writing this code?
- Is there a technical name for this type of list?

I perused [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) in hopes that I could put something there to use.

Thank you for helping me learn.

Comment: `[range(5094, 5095+n) for n in range(6)]`?

Comment: turn it into the answer.

Comment: Yes. That is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: `min, max = 5904, 5909; intLists = [ range(min, x) for x in range(min + 1, max + 2) ]`

Comment: + 1 for putting the minimum and maximum into variables. I will use this version. Thank you for helping me learn. (I changed min, max to minimum and maximum since `min` and `max` are already defined functions in Python.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3.x

```
[list(range(x,5908)) for x in range(5904,5908)]

Out[17]: [[5904, 5905, 5906, 5907], [5905, 5906, 5907], [5906, 5907], [5907]]
```

Comment: I used this in my code: `minimum, maximum = 5904, 5909; [list(range(minimum, x)) for x in range(minimum + 1, maximum + 2)]`

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to use `range` one time only:

```
def func(start, end):
    l = range(start, end)
    return [l[i:] for i,e in enumerate(l)]

In [248]: func(5904,5910)
Out[248]:
[[5904, 5905, 5906, 5907, 5908, 5909],
 [5905, 5906, 5907, 5908, 5909],
 [5906, 5907, 5908, 5909],
 [5907, 5908, 5909],
 [5908, 5909],
 [5909]]
```

If you want the reverse order, just change `[l[i:] for i,e in enumerate(l)]` with `[l[i:] for i,e in enumerate(reversed(l))]`